# Deutsch's Algorithm. Unitary Transform $U_f$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, algorithms

I'm studying Deutsch's algorithm and I keep coming across the phrase along the lines of "There is a unitary transform (a sequence of quantum gates) $U_f$ that transforms the state $|x\rangle |y\rangle \rightarrow |x\rangle |y \oplus f(x)\rangle$".

I was trying to figure out how this  $U_f$ would be implemented as a sequence of quantum gates.

I originally thought that there would be some sort of transform that takes $|x\rangle \rightarrow |f(x)\rangle$ and then apply the CNOT transformation to obtain the result. However, I believe this way of thinking is incorrect and I wouldn't obtain the state desired.

So how is the transform $U_f$ realised or does it depend upon the function $f$?

Comment: Quantum circuits have to be reversible.  If you would map $\vert x\rangle \rightarrow \vert f(x)\rangle$, this might not be reversible (e.g. for the constant function).  Thus, the way to deal with it is to use an ancilla $\vert y \rangle$ in which the result is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $U_f$ must depend on $f$. Let's consider the two trivial examples:

1. $f$ is the zero-function. In this case, $U_f$ is just the identity.
2. $f$ is the one-function ($x\mapsto 1$), then $|x\rangle|y\rangle \mapsto |x\rangle|y\oplus 1\rangle$, then $U_f$ is a NOT-gate on the second qubit.

Just a note: The whole idea of the Deutsch-Josza algorithm is that you don't need to worry about how to implement $U_f$ - it is given.

Comment: @ZachDean Note that *how* to realize such a function is shown in [C. H. Bennett, IBM Journal of Research and Development **17**, 525 (1973)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall04/cos576/papers/bennett73.html). (This is for classical circuits, but every classical reversible circuit equals a unitary.)

Comment: With the circuit diagram for the transform $U_f$ we have the two inputs $x$ and $y$ and the two outputs $x$ and $y \oplus f(x)$.
However, can we not obtain an entangled state as the output, i.e that it can't be written as the tensor product of the two outputs from $U_f$?

For example $|x\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle +|1\rangle$) and $|y\rangle = |0\rangle$ then the combined input state to $U_f$ is
$|input\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$

Then if $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1)=0$ the output will be

$|ouptut\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$ ?

Comment: @ZachDean Why should your input be $\lvert00\rangle+\lvert11\rangle$? It is $\lvert00\rangle+\lvert10\rangle$. The output is correct though, and this is an entangled state. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry I see my error. 

However, if it was possible to obtain an output as an entangled state from $U_f$ then I feel the circuit diagram of $U_f$ is misleading. This is because it shows that the output is $|x\rangle$ and $|y\oplus \rangle$, my point being it may not always be possible to seperate the combined state into these two outputs?

Does this mean that $U_f$ never produces an entangled output?

Comment: @ZachDean Didn't you just yourself give an example above for a function which can give an entangled output for a classical function? Note that the notation only says that for *classical* inputs the output is unentangled.  P.S.: If you want me to be notified about your comments you should add @NorbertSchuch in them.`

Comment: @NorbertSchuh I'm just slightly confused how if we can obtain an entangled state from $U_f$ we can use the circuit diagram with two outputs, which could then be linked to other gates as they are in the Deutsch-Joza algorithm. Surely if we obtain an entangled states we can not then operate on each qubit separately?

My understanding of the transform $U_f$ is that if we have the input state as $|x\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ and $|y\rangle = c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle$

Then the output would be
$ac|0,f(0)> + ad|0,1\oplus f(0)> + bc|1,f(1)> + bd|1,1\oplus f(1)>$

Comment: @ZachDean Of course we can then still operate on the qubits independently, e.g. flip the second qubit, or apply a Hadamard, etc., only the state of those qubits will still be described by an entangled state.  Just write it out as you did above. P.S.: If you misspell my name, I still don't get notified.  The system should offer you autocompletion.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch   Right ok. So if we say had the entangled state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ and say apply a Hadamard gate to the first qubit only, how would the output state look? (P.s thank you for the help)

Comment: @ZachDean SE keeps telling us to avoid extended discussions ... so maybe you want to post this as a question.  However, first (i) search if this has been asked previously (I would suspect so) and (ii) first try to figure out yourself (and explain what you tried in your question). You might also have a look at some openly available QI texts like Preskill's lecture notes, these things are explained there.  (BTW, the brief answer to your question is $(\lvert00\rangle+\lvert01\rangle+\lvert10\rangle-\lvert11\rangle)/2$, in case this helps.)